# grunt-contrib-jade compiling to single JS with cwd

Tags: gruntjs, pug

I am trying to compile multiple jade templates into single JS file using grunt-contrib-jade. Problem I'm facing is that with full path to templates, I get function names with full path. I want to avoid that, so I tried using cwd (without expand). This ended up with the following:

```
>> Source file "test.jade" not found.
>> Source file "test2.jade" not found.
```

Is there any way I could achieve what I plan? My grunt config for that task is as following:

```
jade: {
  js: {
    options: {
      client: true,
      amd: true
    },
    files: [ {
      cwd: 'js/views/',
      src: ['*.jade'],
      dest: 'js/tmp/templates.js'
    } ]
  }
},
```

Thanks in advice,
Dracco

Comment: as far as i know `grunt-contrib-jade` does not concat

Comment: It does ;). It works with below config, just has full paths as function names:
    `files: [ {
          src: 'js/views/*.jade',
          dest: 'js/tmp/templates.js'
    } ]`

Comment: that's weird. I tried it and it was not working. Maybe, i am doing something wrong. This is how my config looks like http://output.jsbin.com/tobute/1.js

Comment: Because the `expand: true`, grunt runs jade separately for each file, meaning that you will end up with multiple files. If you remove it however, it ends up bringing errors I posted :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, didn't fully read the documentation of the plugin :(.

The solution is trivial, using the `processName` option:

```
options: {
      client: true,
      amd: true,
      processName: function(path) {
        var pathChunks = path.split('.')[0].split('/');
        return pathChunks[pathChunks.length - 1];
      }
    }
```